# yaml frontmatter in org mode

Tags: org-mode, html, markdown

When exporting and org file in emacs to either html or md for a jekyll-based web page, the `yaml` front matter gets twisted.

As suggested [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-jekyll.html), I have attempted enclosing it in an html block in the org file thus:

```
#+begin_html
---
layout: post 
title:  "La redistritación"
---
#+end_html
```

It should output this:

```
---
layout: post 
title:  "La redistritación"
---
```

Using `org-html-publish-to-html`, I instead get this:

```
<div class="html">
<p>
&#x2014;
layout: post 
title:  "La redistritación"
&#x2014;
</p>
</div>
```

I also attempted enclosing in a source block (as suggested [here](https://tamouse.github.io/swaac/emacs/org-mode/2015/05/25/using-emacss-org-mode-and-editing-yaml-frontmatter-in-jekyll-posts/)) thus:

```
#+begin_src yaml
---
layout: post 
title:  "La redistritación"
---
#+end_src
```

which comes close, but prepends empty (code) spaces and is therefore not recognized as front matter by jekyll.

(And adding `exports` and `results` specs, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430346/edit-yaml-frontmatter-in-org-mode-blog-post-destined-for-jekyll), returns a `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` error message.)

How should I configure export settings to get proper yaml front matter?

Comment: Please do not post the same question on StackOverflow and emacs.SE - choose one or the other. Please delete one of these posts. Thx.

Comment: Upgrading `org-mode` seems to have taken care of the error message. It now exports front-matter that `jekyll` recognizes as such. But am still puzzled as to why the first approach will not work...

Comment: If you think the question and answer might help someone else then please post your answer as an actual answer (not a comment). You can accept your own answer. If you don't think the Q&A is likely to help someone else then consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't see what version you are running but the solution is crazy simple. Mine didn't work at first (because i used yml not yaml) Those two file types are the same thing.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC yaml
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a filter to post-process the entire document body in order to expand expressions of the form `{{{:ident}}}` by resolving :ident against the communication channel. For example `{{{:title}}}` will be replaced by the document title as set by the `#+title` directive.

```
(defun my-org-body-filter (body backend info)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "{{{\\(:[^}]+\\)}}}"
                            (lambda (name)
                              (let* ((sym (intern (substring name 3 -3)))
                                     (val (plist-get info sym)))
                                (format "%s "(and val (car val)))))
                            body))
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-body-functions #'my-org-body-filter)
```